# Referencing class variable in class method Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm defining a class in Javascript meant to serve as an audioplayer compatible with iOS. I'm just getting started with the basics, and running into an issue when trying to access a class method.

After creating an instance of the class (`var audio = new WebAudio('soundfile.mp3', document.querySelector(#sound_div)`), and attempting to access the method `audio.playSound()`, I'm getting:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: elem on line 29

```
class WebAudio {

    constructor(soundFile, elem) {
        this.soundFile = soundFile;
        this.elem = elem;
    }

    context() {
        var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
        var context = new AudioContext();
        return context;
    }

    webAudioTouchUnlock(context) {
       return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       //if AudioContext is suspended, and window has been interacted with
           if (context.state === 'suspended' && 'ontouchstart' in window) {
           console.log(context.state);
           var unlock = function() {
               //resume AudioContext (allow playing sound), remove event listeners
               context.resume().then(function() {
                   console.log("context resumed");
                   this.elem.removeEventListener('touchstart', unlock);
                   this.elem.removeEventListener('touchend', unlock);
                   resolve(true);
               }, function (reason) {
                   reject(reason);
               });
           };
           this.elem.addEventListener('touchstart', unlock, false); //error
           this.elem.addEventListener('touchend', unlock, false);
           } else {
               console.log('context not suspended? Context is ' + context.state);
               resolve(false);
           }
       });
    }

    playSound() {
        this.webAudioTouchUnlock(this.context()).then(function (unlocked) {
            if(unlocked) {
                console.log('playing audio file');
                var audio = new Audio('sound/' + soundFile);
                if (!audio.playing) {
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    audio.pause();
                }
            }
        }, function(reason) {
            console.error(reason);
        });
        document.body.addEventListener('load', playSound(soundFile));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's some example input? What arguments would you pass to `new WebAudio`?

Comment: @JackBashford thanks for the reply, usage is in the question. "var audio = new WebAudio('soundfile.mp3', document.querySelector(#sound_div)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose the binding to `this` when you pass the function to an event listener:

```
var unlock = function() {
               //resume AudioContext (allow playing sound), remove event listeners
               context.resume().then(function() {
                   console.log("context resumed");
                   // this won't point to the instance when called by listener
                   this.elem.removeEventListener('touchstart', unlock);
                   this.elem.removeEventListener('touchend', unlock);
                   resolve(true);
               }, function (reason) {
                   reject(reason);
               });
           };
           this.elem.addEventListener('touchstart', unlock, false); //error
```

Arrow functions or manually calling `bind(this)` can fix it. The arrow function will bind `this` in the function lexically, which means `this` will be the `this` value from where it was defined rather than how it is called:

```
var unlock = () => {
               //resume AudioContext (allow playing sound), remove event listeners
               context.resume().then(() => {
                   console.log("context resumed");
                   this.elem.removeEventListener('touchstart', unlock);
                   this.elem.removeEventListener('touchend', unlock);
                   resolve(true);
               }, function (reason) {
                   reject(reason);
               });
           };
           this.elem.addEventListener('touchstart', unlock, false); //error
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.elem') — webAudio.js:29 - audio.elem holds the correct reference though

Comment: @froggomad sorry, there's a lot of nested  functions here. You probably need to defined you Promise callback with an arrow function too: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...`

Comment: Thanks, you lead me on the right path... couldn't have done it without you. Needed `this.webAudioTouchUnlock(this.context()).then( (unlocked) =>` in `playSound()` and a separate function to add the listener

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out @froggomad.